How to fix "fatal error: ext/pb_ds/detail/resize_policy/hash_standard_resize_policy_imp.hpp: No such file or directory"
I want to use ordered_set in C++, for that I copied the header files from here.
The header files are:
include <ext/pb_ds/assoc_container.hpp>
include <ext/pb_ds/tree_policy.hpp>

When I compile the code, the following error occurs:
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\ext\pb_ds\detail\standard_policies.hpp:45,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\ext\pb_ds\assoc_container.hpp:47,
                 from 0.cpp:8:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\ext\pb_ds\hash_policy.hpp:610:10: fatal error: ext/pb_ds/detail/resize_policy/hash_standard_resize_policy_imp.hpp: No such file or directory
  610 | #include <ext/pb_ds/detail/resize_policy/hash_standard_resize_policy_imp.hpp>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated."

I checked multiple online resources, which suggested upgrading gcc which I upgraded to gcc 9, I thought to update C++ on my compiler, but failed to do so, it shows I am using C++14. When I used "g++ 'file_name.cpp' -std g++=c++2a", it threw the same error.
Searched for multiple solutions, found one solution to implement ordered_set from scratch but that would be a mess. I want to use the template.

Upgrade GCC: uninstall that you installed and use https://www.msys2.org/

When you use external libraries, do not just copy files. Use a package manager so that it can set include and link paths for you. Note that C++ by default has : std::set which is ordered and has std::unordered_set which is not

Side note, forget geeksforgeeks exists, it is a very low quality source and often gets C++ things wrong.

@PepijnKramer I want to access elements in the set using their indices, like in an array, for that normal set has a time complexity of O(n), using iterator, oredred_set allows it to be done in O(log n).

Maybe it is better to explain what you want to do, because accessing a "set" based on an  "index" in log complexity does not really make sense to me

https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/123624. You could check it here.
It can be used when we need to find the median of an array with a window size of k over complete array. For this we can insert k values in the set and take the middle value and insert the last and remove the first element. There will be many better use cases but for now we could consider it.

I have got my mistake it should be done as follows -
#include <ext/pb_ds/assoc_container.hpp>
#include <ext/pb_ds/tree_policy.hpp>
using namespace __gnu_pbds;
#define ordered_set tree<pair<int,int>, null_type,less<pair<int,int>>, rb_tree_tag,tree_order_statistics_node_update>

You shouldn't copy these header files from anywhere because your chosen compiler already has them. They work out of the box with a fresh gcc installation, with no additional actions needed.
By copying them from an unknown place and overwriting files that came with your compiler you may welll have damaged your compiler installation. You need to wipe it and install from scratch. (I recommend the msys2 installation method, as most people do these days).

Actually, my compiler is working completely fine. I am a college student and we do Competitive Programming. My friends are using these in VS Code and it's working fine for them. I don't know what the issue is with my compiler or if anything else is causing this issue.

"my compiler is working completely fine." Since you are experiencing an issue that others don't, it is obviously not working completely fine. "I don't know what the issue is with my compiler or if anything else is causing this issue." The answer to that is right above.

by working completely fine i meant for other purposes. Every other thing (which i know) is fine except this.

You overwrote two header files with who knows what, and now including these files doesn't work. Things that do not require including these files still work. I wonder what could be the reason for that.

As said by others, including the files as if they are not part of the STL does not work. What you should include is set, without specifying the path explicitly.
In set the elements are sorted internally already, I'm not sure why you want to explicitly have an 'ordered' set.
If you mean keep the elements in the order of insertion, the you probably want a queue or even a list.
If you insist on using set (e.g., to avoid duplicates) you could do something like this.
